# jQuery jAlert Options list

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jAlert plugin and saw recently a param i didn't care till today... is the options list.

Usage:

```
$.jAlert([message], [highlight level], function() {
    //callback
}, [options]);
```

I've been searching for a while but did not see the options list anywhere.

Does anyone know where to get all the params of this list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all are you sure that there is some parameter called `option`.

From plugin js file it seems that,parameters that are used with jAlert are:

```
jAlert(msg, type, uid, alert_box_width, yoffset)
```